# Python Date format conversion to UK

Tags: python, csv, date

I have a CSV file which has a date column with some dirty data i.e. dates stored in different formats (US and UK). I'd like to create another CSV file with the dates converted so they are consistently stored in the UK format enabling me to import correctly into my SQL database. [image: CSV with 'Date' column to be converted]

I'd like the dates to be converted to the following format:

'05-12-2017'
'07-11-2017'
'24-04-1999'
'28-01-1987'..

I tried the following code:

```
df = F.pd.read_csv('Book1.csv', parse_dates = [0], dayfirst = True)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(F.pd.to_datetime, format = '%m/%d/%Y')
df['date_eu'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
df
```

, but it throws an error while trying to convert the US dates

> ```
> ValueError: time data '20/01/2018' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)
> ```

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: "it throws an error" -- is there a stack trace that you can [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47654716/edit) to your question?

Comment: If your input data is mixed format dates - how do you know when it's one format or another to start with?

Comment: 4/24/1999 is unique, but what about 05/12/2017  that could be 5th Dec or 12th Mai - not unique. The error probably stems from trying to parse 4/24/1999 with %m - %m needs zero padded months, see [python3ref:strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: You need to use additional information from table (if there's so) to define to what country date belongs to. Because what about such cases 01/01/2017?

Comment: The error is: `ValueError: time data '20/01/2018' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)`. I agree with the comments..the error stems from trying to convert the American date formats since the month falls out of range. There isn't any additional info in the table to determine which region the date belongs to. I was hoping that I could somehow use Python to apply a rule which would try to interpret dates in the UK format dd/mm/yyyy by default (eg. '05/12/2017' should be interpreted as 5th Dec 2017)

Comment: And where it cannot directly interpret it as UK format (eg. in case of  '4/24/1999', it should understand that the date is stored in mm/dd/yyyy format and then it can convert it to dd/mm/yyyy i.e. to 24th April 1999. Not sure if this is even possible?

Comment: @khelwood I have updated my post with the error description. I've also added a few comments above. Thanks

Comment: So if your dates are going to be some month-first and some day-first, how are you going to know which way to parse them? What would you like `1/2/2000` to be parsed as?

Comment: @khelwood This should be parsed as `1st February 2000`. By default, it should be parsed as `dd/mm/yyyy`. Only if that's not possible, ex. in case of `04/24/1999`, should Python resort to interpreting it as `mm/dd/yyyy` and then save it in the dataframe in the `dd/mm/yyyy` format as `24/04/1999`. Hope this makes sense

Comment: That is information that should have been in your original question. But anyway. Try and parse it day-first, and if raises an exception, parse it month-first.

Comment: @khelwood yes, not sure how to do that (handle exceptions etc.). I'm very new to Python. Could you please help with that? Thanks

Comment: @PatrickArtner 05/12/2017 should be parsed as 5th Dec. By default, it should be parsed as dd/mm/yyyy. Only if that's not possible, ex. in case of 04/24/1999, should Python resort to interpreting it as mm/dd/yyyy and then save it in the dataframe in the dd/mm/yyyy format as 24/04/1999. Is there a quick way I can parse it day-first and then, if required, month-first? Thanks

Comment: @V.Asher see answer for a `def` that accomplishes a "us"-first else "en"  approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Try-Parse-Else-Approach:

```
from datetime import datetime

def normalizeDateString(ds):
    '''normalizes a date of format "d / d / dddd " to "dd/dd/dddd"'''
    sp = ds.replace(" ","").split("/")
    if len(sp[0])==1:
        sp[0]="0"+sp[0]
    if len(sp[1])==1:
        sp[1]="0"+sp[1]

    return sp[0]+"/"+sp[1]+"/"+sp[2]

def parseDT(dateString):
    ''' parses "dd/dd/yyyy" as US (month/day/year). Fallback: day/month/year on error'''
    try:
        repl =  normalizeDateString(dateString)        
        return datetime.strptime(repl, "%m/%d/%Y").date()
    except:
        return datetime.strptime(repl, "%d/%m/%Y").date()


print(parseDT("14/12/2018"))
print(parseDT("2/5/2018")) # ok for US
print(parseDT("22/5/2018")) # not ok for US
print(parseDT("12/2/2018"))
print(parseDT("2/1/2018"))
```

Output:

```
2018-12-14
2018-02-05  # US ok
2018-05-22  # EN by except
2018-12-02
2018-02-01
```

HTH

Comment: One quick question though, how can I apply this function to a date column in a dataframe. When I do the following I get an error that **'Series' object has no attribute 'split'** `df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')
df['Date'] = parseDT(df['Date'])`

Comment: I am not much into df - but this line `df['Date'].apply(F.pd.to_datetime, format = '%m/%d/%Y')` looks as if you apply a function to each value in the series , does replacing `F.pd.to_datetime` by `parseDT` and omitting `format = ... ` work?

Comment: @V.Asher see comment before && https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html   - try `df['Date'].apply(parseDT)`

Comment: Thanks, this works. I had to make a small tweak in the `normalizeDateString()` and `parseDT()` functions to account for nulls (missing dates) and then apply the function to the dataframe column as `df['Date'].apply(parseDT)`. Thanks!