# How to omit the cells in CSV file when their value is "00/00/0000" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Hello I have a code to convert US dates into UK ones from the following topic:
[Python Date format conversion to UK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47654716/python-date-format-conversion-to-uk?rq=1).

However, the files which I have contain cells with 00/00/0000 as date and I get the error:

> ValueError: time data '00/00/0000' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'

How can I avoid this error in my code, please?

````
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd


from datetime import datetime

def normalizeDateString(ds):
# normalizes a date of format "d / d / dddd " to "dd/dd/dddd" ```
    sp = ds.replace(" ","").split("/")
    if len(sp[0])==1:
        sp[0]="0"+sp[0]
    if len(sp[1])==1:
        sp[1]="0"+sp[1]

    return sp[0]+"/"+sp[1]+"/"+sp[2]

def parseDT(dateString):
# parses "dd/dd/yyyy" as US (month/day/year). Fallback to (day/month/year) on error'''
    try:
        repl =  normalizeDateString(dateString)        
        return datetime.strptime(repl, "%m/%d/%Y").date()

    except:
        return datetime.strptime(repl, "%d/%m/%Y").date()


cwd = os.getcwd()

directory = cwd + '\\'

delheadfiles = ['USR02', 'USR06']

for delheadfile in delheadfiles:   
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        if file.endswith(delheadfile + "_FINAL.csv"):       
            data = pd.read_csv(directory + delheadfile +  '_FINAL.csv', sep=",", low_memory=False, encoding='latin-1')
            data['GLTGB'].apply(parseDT)
            print(data)
            data.to_csv(directory + delheadfile +'_FINAL.csv', sep=',', index=False)
````

Comment: What you are doing is not the pandas way to parse datetime, look at [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). In your case: `pd.to_datetime('column_name', format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to_datetime`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"GLTGB": ["00/00/0000", "10/02/2019"]})
print(pd.to_datetime(df['GLTGB'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce').fillna("Error"))
```

**Output:**

```
0                  Error
1    2019-02-10 00:00:00
Name: GLTGB, dtype: object
```

Comment: Can I ask you how to get rid off the trailing time, please? I mean 00:00:00?

Comment: Do you want to delete the row with `00:00:0000` ?

Comment: No, I just need to display the date without the time. so '2019-02-10' instead of '2019-02-10 00:00:00'. Thank you!

Comment: `print(pd.to_datetime(df['GLTGB'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce').dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y").fillna("Error"))`